# Does this Maven range dependency error makes sense?

Tags: maven

I'm working with a "pom" dependency that defines this dependency

```
<groupId>com.oracle.toplink</groupId>
<artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
<version>[12.2.1,12.2.2)</version>
```

And in the repository, the maven-metadata of eclipselink contains the following

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.oracle.toplink</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>12.2.1-0-0</latest>
    <release>12.2.1-0-0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20161123223550</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

But Maven throws this error

`Couldn't find a version in [12.1.2-0-0, 12.1.3-0-0, 12.2.1-0-0] to match range [12.2.1,12.2.2)`

If I'm not wrong, Maven should've matched with the `12.2.1-0-0` version.

Why does this happen?

Also, there are two more versions in the repository `12.2.1-1-0 and 12.2.1-2-0` but these do not appear in the maven-metadata of eclipselink (any idea why?)

Answer (score 0):

If really do a comparsion of the version in Maven via:

`$ java -jar apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\apache-artifact-3.3.9.jar 12.2.1-1-0 12.2.1
Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 12.2.1-1-0 == 12.2.1-1
   12.2.1-1-0 > 12.2.1
2. 12.2.1 == 12.2.1`

You see that `12.2.1 is something different than`12.2.1-1-0`

Furthermore if you use `12.2.1-0-0` and compare it to `12.2.1` via:

`$ java -jar apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\apache-artifact-3.3.9.jar 12.2.1-0-0 12.2.1
Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 12.2.1-0-0 == 12.2.1
   12.2.1-0-0 == 12.2.1
2. 12.2.1 == 12.2.1`

You see that there is no difference between those versions.

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Versioning
- https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-artifact/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html
- http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-artifact/index.html

Comment: Hello thanks, for answering. I forgot to say that this behavior is present on Maven 2.2.1. Do you think that could be a bug that 2.2.1 do not compare correctly that kind of version syntax?